# C# make a Dictionary of Lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I'm having a trouble defining a Dictionary for quick accessing Lambda Expressions.

Let's suppose we have a well-known class like this:

```
class Example
{
    public string Thing1;
    public DateTime Thing2;
    public int Thing3;
}
```

What a want to do is something like this:

```
var getters = new Dictionary<string, IDontKnowWhatGoesHere>();
getters.Add("Thing1", x => x.Thing1);
getters.Add("Thing3", x => x.Thing3);
```

Is this possible?

Edit:

This is my use case for this object:

```
List<Example> array = new List<Example>();

// We actually get this variable set by the user
string sortField = "Thing2";

array.Sort(getters[sortField]);
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You are trying to store a `Func<Example, string>` as the value type in the dictionary? Is this what you want? What are you trying to use this for?

Comment: so you want to store expressions?

Comment: Can you say what for you need this? Then we will write better solution.

Comment: Why use a dictionary at all? Why not have a `List<Example>`? Then you can use linq on that. No need to limit the amount of data you can hold.

Comment: Hey, I want to have a quick access to the lambda expressions. For example... IEnumerable<Example> a; a.OrderBy(getters["Thing3"])

Comment: Why not implement an extension method of 'Example' to create the getters you want?  (I assume by "well-known" you mean some library class you can't edit yourself to add the getter you want.)  Or if it's really just grabbing properties by name, reflection might be useful.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore By well-known class I mean, it is not anonymous. So it is defined in a file which I can change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a couple of options.  If, as in your example, the things you want to get are all the same type (i.e. `String`), you can do

```
var getters = new Dictionary<string, Func<Example, String>>();
```

However, if they're different types, you'll need to use the lowest common subclass, which in most cases will be `Object`:

```
var getters = new Dictionary<string, Func<Example, object>>();
```

Note that you'll then need to cast the return value into your expected type.

Comment: By key, yes.  By Value, not really: delegates do not implement `IComparable`, so you'll need to write your own `IComparer`.  If that's your intention, you might find it easier to use expressions, as in `Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Example, string>>` - but that's a whole new problem.

Comment: I'm sorry you got me wrong, I want to do this: List<Example> a; a.OrderBy(getters["Thing1"]); The problem that I need to solve is to make dynamic OrderBy without writing the mega massive switch case. The Sort field is coming from client-side

Comment: @AdrianSalazar I hadn't noticed your edit.  It will work fine in that case, even with `Func<Example, object>`.

Comment: Thanks I have implemented it and it works. Lightweight dynamic sort without using reflection...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var getters = new Dictionary<string, Func<Example, object>>();
getters.Add("Thing1", x => x.Thing1);
getters.Add("Thing3", x => x.Thing3);
```

The first generic type parameter of the `Func` delegate is the type of the input, and the second generic type parameter is the type of the output (use `object` because you've different output types).
More about `Func`: [`Func<T, TResult>` Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
var getters = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Example, object>>>();
```

However, `string Thing1` should be public.

Comment: Will this work well in this case? IEnumerable<Example>.OrderBy(getters["Thing1"])

Answer (score 1):

I really think you are thinking about this in the wrong way. Why use a dictionary at all? If your class definition is correct, then just use a `List<Example>`.

```
List<Example> dataList = new List<Example>();
dataList.Add(new Example { Thing1 = "asdf", Thing2 = "qwert", Thing3 = 2 });
```

Then you can use linq on it.

```
IEnumerable<Example> sortedByT3 = dataList.OrderBy(x => x.Thing3);

sortedByT3.Last().Thing2 = "hjkl";
```

You can also use a `dynamic order by` provided by [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/1043380):

```
var sortedByString = dataList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Thing2");
```

No need for lambdas, just direct access to the data.

As everyone has said, you need to make the members public. I would suggest you change it to the following:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Thing1 { get; set; }
    public string Thing2 { get; set; }
    public int Thing3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes I get your point, the thing is that I need to know on which field I want to sort on the first time. So I can make a big switch case like our ancient programmers normally did. I can live with that, but I would like to know if DLR, TypeInference, Generics and Lambdas can give me another way of doing it.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar, so something like `dynamic linq`? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Yes you got my point, but I'm not connected to SQL at all... and I don't want to save the world in one day and make it mega-generic. If it works with this particular class, then it's enough.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar, ok, I see what you mean. I will leave you will one more suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41244/1043380 , and I will keep this answer up for future reference.